Finiteness of the number of Hopf subalgebras
Let $H$ be a finite-dimensional Hopf algebra over the complex field.
Question: Does $ H $ have a finite number of Hopf subalgebras?
In the case where $ H $ is semisimple, the answer is yes. According to [EW14, Theorem 3.6], a semisimple Hopf algebra over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero has a finite number of right coideal subalgebras. Furthermore, [EW14, Example 3.5] presents a non-semisimple example—Sweedler's 4-dimensional Hopf algebra—that has infinitely many right coideal subalgebras, though it does have a finite number of Hopf subalgebras. Please note that [EW14, Theorem 3.6] has been generalized to apply to any algebraically closed field, as stated in [S17, Theorem 1].

Reference
[EW14] Etingof, Pavel; Walton, Chelsea. Semisimple Hopf actions on commutative domains. Adv. Math. 251 (2014), 47--61.
[S17] Skryabin, Serge. Finiteness of the number of coideal subalgebras. Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 145 (2017), no. 7, 2859--2869.

No. Following discussions with Pavel Etingof and Serge Skryabin, the Nichols' Hopf algebras $ H_{2^n} $ described below, initially introduced in [N78] and further discussed in [EG04, §2.2], present a family of counterexamples for $n \ge 3$.
Nichols' Hopf algebra $ H_{2^n} $ (for $ n \geq 1 $) is a $ 2^n $-dimensional Hopf algebra generated by elements $ g, x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1} $ satisfying the following relations:
$$
g^2 = 1, \
x_i g = -g x_i, \
x_i^2 = 0, \
x_i x_j = -x_j x_i \ (i \neq j), \
\Delta(g) = g \otimes g,
\Delta(x_i) = g \otimes x_i + x_i \otimes 1, \
\epsilon(g) = 1, \
\epsilon(x_i) = 0, \
S(g) = g, \
S(x_i) = -g x_i.
$$
For $ n=1 $, this algebra corresponds to the group algebra of the cyclic group of order 2. For $ n=2 $, it represents Sweedler's 4-dimensional Hopf algebra. When $ n \ge 3 $, it contains infinitely many Hopf subalgebras. Specifically, for every subspace $ E \subset \bigoplus_i \mathbb{C}x_i$, the subalgebra $ H_E = \langle E, g \rangle $ is a Hopf subalgebra, since for all $x \in E$ then $\Delta(x) = g \otimes x + x \otimes 1$ and $S(x) = -g x$. It has dimension $ 2^{\dim(E)+1}$, and is completely characterized by $ E $.

References
[EG04] Etingof, Pavel; Gelaki, Shlomo. Finite dimensional quasi-Hopf algebras with radical of codimension 2. Math. Res. Lett. 11 (2004), no. 5-6, 685--696.
[N78] Nichols, Warren D. Bialgebras of type one. Comm. Algebra 6 (1978), no. 15, 1521--1552.
